# Add fill to comic-style font in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, I'm using the Komika Glaze font, styled like the drop shadows that you might see in a comic book.  So, the shapes formed by the font itself should remain black.  But, the interiors of the letters are transparent.  So, when placed over a colored background, e.g. yellow, it appears as though I'm using a yellow font on a yellow background.  How can I easily select the interiors of the letters to fill them with white?   For example, in the letter 'o', there are four concentric circles (outside-in): the outside shadow, the interior, the inner shadow, and the inner transparent area.  How can I select just the interior, without selecting the inner transparent area?

Comment: I'm confused... can you post (or link to) a screenshot showing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me you want to create something similar to what is shown below.
[image]

The sample above uses the komika glaze font on top of a red background.  Using the original font as-is this will appear as a red font on a red background as you had described.  Here's what I did to change the color of the interior sections:

- Select text then do Path -> Object to path.  This converts the object to a path.
- Now select the Fill bounded areas tool (the paint bucket), select the your color of choice and click inside the areas you want filled.  For this example, I used white.
- After you're done with steps 1 and 2, select all the letters in your text (select each letter while holding down the shift key) and then do Object -> Group.

The last step makes helps put the text back together, which is useful is you need to resize or move.